# Обработка ошибок try catch

Tags: php

Как сделать, чтобы не показывало саму ошибку?

```
try {
      if(!$userPath = mkdir('./userFile/'.$_SESSION['user'].'/question/' . $date . '/'  , 0700, true)) {
          throw new Exception('Ошибка.');
          die();
       }
     } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo '<p>Произошла ошибка.</p>' . $e->getMessage();
        die();
     }
```

Показывает `Warning: mkdir(): Not a directory`

Comment: Убрать . $e->getMessage()

Comment: Не работает, всё равно показывает Warning: mkdir(): Not a directory

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    if(!$userPath = mkdir('./userFile/'.$_SESSION['user'].'/question/' . $date . '/'  , 0700, true)) {
        throw new Exception('Ошибка.');
        exit;
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {}
```

Comment: не работает, показывает Warning: mkdir(): Not a directory

Comment: так это не ошибка, а предупреждение, хотя в любом случае у меня работает.
если это на хостинге может быть прав нету на создание файлов или еще что то подобное...

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите убрать предупреждение - достаточно на странице или в файле конфига `php.ini` отключить вывод предупреждений, к примеру вот такой код не выдаст предупреждение:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING); //отключаем предупреждения на этой странице 
//Дальше ваш код
try {
    if(!$userPath = mkdir('./userFile/'.$_SESSION['user'].'/question/' . $date . '/'  , 0700, true)) {
        throw new Exception('Ошибка.');
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo '<p>Произошла ошибка.</p>' . $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

P.S. Только если действительно весь код, не понимаю зачем вы тут `try-catch` используете.

Answer (score 0):

Подавить предупреждения для какой-то функции можно добавив "собаку" перед её вызовом:

```
if(!$userPath = @mkdir('./userFile/'.$_SESSION['user'].'/') {
    // ...
```

Это стоит делать только если вы сами обрабатываете ошибку. Хорошо будет проверять что каталог есть, не вызывая его создание без необходимости.

Отключать предупреждения для всего кода ради одного случая - не лучшая идея.

```
// не делайте так
// error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING);
```